# How to ignore React Native parent Padding?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So my view as follows:

```
<View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 20}}>
  <View style={{ padding: 10, backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
    <Text style={{ fontSize: 12 }}>Passenger Details</Text>
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
      <View>
        <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold',  fontSize: 16}}>Male</Text>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 14}}>Male, 26 years</Text>
      </View>
      <View>
        <Text>L23</Text>
      </View>
    </View>

    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
      <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold',  fontSize: 16}}>Bus Operator GST</Text>
      <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold',  fontSize: 16}}>₹ 143.90</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
```

So by this, the second view in the above has a background color! So, I need to be without padding for that alone!

So, How to override the parent padding and have 0 padding for a particular child component?

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
<View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 20}}>
  <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 0,paddingVertical: 10, backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
    <Text style={{ fontSize: 12 }}>Passenger Details</Text>
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
      <View>
        <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold',  fontSize: 16}}>Male</Text>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 14}}>Male, 26 years</Text>
      </View>
      <View>
        <Text>L23</Text>
      </View>
    </View>

    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
      <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold',  fontSize: 16}}>Bus Operator GST</Text>
      <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold',  fontSize: 16}}>₹ 143.90</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
```

Comment: Some explanation of what your snippet is doing or why might be nice...